# How to set an element that I am toggling to be collapsed on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to figure out how to make an element that I am toggling on `click` with jQuery collapsed when the page initially loads. Everything is open on load at the moment - exactly the opposite of what I need.

Keeping in mind that I'm a beginner, can someone please help me? Thanks.

```
// Toggle       
$('.togglehandle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next('.toggledata').slideToggle();
});

// alert close 
$('.clostalert').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.alert').fadeOut ();
    $('#options').hide();
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the class to "active" on the HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

First off, remember to set your `".toggledata"` element to `display: none` in the CSS.

Also, make sure that the two handlers you posted are all wrapped in `$(document).ready()`. In other words, make sure you have something like the below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Toggle       
    $('.togglehandle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).next('.toggledata').slideToggle();
    });

    // alert close 
    $('.clostalert').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('.alert').fadeOut ();
        $('#options').hide();
    }); 
});
```

And just because you mentioned that you are a beginner..........here it is with just a little code cleanup ;)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Toggle       
    $('.togglehandle').on('click', function() { //1: .click() -> .on('click',
        var $this = $(this); //2: $(this) -> var $this = $(this)
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        $this.next('.toggledata').slideToggle();
    });

    // alert close 
    $('.clostalert').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent('.alert').fadeOut(); //3: No change
        $('#options').hide();
    }); 
});
```

Explanation of changes:

1. Changing `.click()` to `.on('click'...`

   The `.click()` method is just shorthand for the `.on('click'...` method. Using the long form doesn't really have any benefits over the shorthand, except that it standardizes your handler bindings and has more options for parameters (like when using delegated events, which you will likely do in the future).
2. Changing `$(this)` to `var $this = $(this)`

   This part is sometimes difficult to wrap your mind around. First and foremost, understand that jQuery, itself, is actually a function object. The developers of jQuery gave the library two names that can both be used interchangeably when coding: `$` and `jQuery`.

   In other words, both of the following are actually equivalent:

   ```
   $('.toggledata').slideToggle();
   ```

   and

   ```
   jQuery('.toggledata').slideToggle();
   ```

   This is important because it must be remembered that the `$` is essentially a function name, used like any other. As such, each time you call `$(this)` you are essentially calling a "constructor" function to initialize a new jQuery object. As such, to make code more efficient, we store `$(this)` in a variable so that it can be reused.

   The variable name `$this` is just a convention (a good one that you should make a habit of using). It is a common convention to prefix the name of any variables that hold jQuery objects with the dollar sign. For example, if we store `$('.clostalert')` in a variable then we would do something like:

   ```
   var $clostalert = $('.clostalert');
   ```
3. Notice that we do not bother to store `$(this)` in a variable in the second handler because it is only used once and thus `$(this)` is only called once there.

Comment: if OP sets display none, your code will open them all on page load (opposite of expectations)...needs to be one or the other

Comment: @charlietfl - Good call; I misread the OP. Updated! :) Thanks so much!